# AndroidStudio: JaCoCo code coverage report's 0% for coverage

Tags: android, android-studio, code-coverage, jacoco

I've recently brought code coverage into my project.  It creates a report, which I can view, and it seems to be working great.

The only problem is it is missing my tests - I don't have GREAT code coverage right now, but it reports 0% coverage for all classes and other files.

I can see the tests being run, and can see them passing, but they aren't being counted.

My configuration is:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.1'
    ...
     debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
}
```

Comment: I have same problem, along with some interesting history. As it happens I have two builds that ran with identical code versions on March 23rd 2015 (real coverage results) and March 24th (zeroed out results). Every build since then (>100) has the results zeroed out. My hypothesis is that something "external", ex: Android SDK, Java JDK, Mac OS version update changed behind our backs to cause this problem.  Also interesting is that the CI build device with zeroed results is a Galaxy S4 on Android 4.4.2 - along with Galaxy S5 on Android 5, but a Moto X with Android 4.4.4 still gets real results!

Comment: LG G2 with Android 5.0.2 also gets non-zero results

Comment: Ok thats really interesting - let me check on some other devices.

Comment: Emulator (with Android 5) also worked.

Answer (score 2):

This might be related to this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=170607

Comment: Thanks yea, you can see me commenting on that for the last few days =)  Thanks for sharing the link though, would have been great to find it earlier.

Comment: I tried the workaround in #4, but it didn't work, and nothing in the conversation quite seems to explain to me why one phone (Samsung Galaxy S4 on Android 4.4.2) has zeros while another (Moto X with Android 4.4.4) gets real coverage results.

Answer (score 0):

It's working (again) with

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
```